# Can't connect to mongo db on OSX through homebrew ("Javascript execution failed"

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I'm trying to install mongo db for the first time on OSX 10.8.3 through Homebrew. Installed Homebrew, then installed mongo and was told that the build was a success. However, when I try to launch mongo using the `mongo` command, I get the following error:

```
JavaScript execution failed: Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:L112
```

Thoughts?

Comment: FYI, the `mongo` command runs the client, which is a separate program (often on a different machine) from the server.  Your problem is that the mongodb server isn't running.  See answers below for how to start the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `brew info mongodb` for instructions on how to start the mongodb server.  It'll say something like:

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

Comment: Thanks, Leopd. I ran that command and I get this: `launchctl: Couldn't stat("/Users/Dan/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist"): No such file or directory nothing found to load`

Comment: Turns out I didn't have the server running like I thought I did.

Comment: I ran into the same issue this morning and found running `brew services restart mongodb` fixed it - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23463293/917187

Answer (score 1):

I was having this issue when I installed mongo through homebrew on osx 10.8.4. The issue was the mongod.conf file was written to

```
/usr/local/etc/ instead of /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment: Can you please clarify this answer, I have no idea what you mean. The config file was written to a directory instead of a file?