# Upgraded mongo to 2.6 using home-brew and now can't connect

Tags: macos, mongodb, upgrade, homebrew

Running OSX 10.9.2, I just ran `brew upgrade mongo` which upgraded my `mongo` to version 2.6

As per the instructions I've run

```
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

But now when I run `mongo` it says

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: test
2014-05-05T10:07:22.769+1000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:61 Connection refused
2014-05-05T10:07:22.770+1000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

#### Things I've tried:

1. I've seen this covered on other SX questions and people have suggested creating a `/data/db` folder but this wasn't needed previously and I don't want to lose the data from my old instance of `mongo`. Regardless, I tried it, and `chown`ed it to allow read/write from my user account, but that made no difference. (FYI my data lives in `/usr/local/var/mongodb/` which is typical I believe for OSX.)
2. A lot of the other questions also assume Linux rather than Mac, or they wade off into `PHP` land which is not relevant to me.
3. I've also tried rebooting my Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by forcing home-brew to restart it.

```
brew services restart mongodb
```

and voila

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.0
connecting to: test
>
```

now works a treat.

Comment: I forgot to restart my shell  and got the same error :).